# Pug for WebStorm on Windows

Tags: pug, webstorm

I did `npm install -g pug` as administrator. But I can't run the pug command on the command line. It seems pug isn't installed:

```
npm config get prefix
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\
```

In this folder there is no pug file.

I want to use pug for the File Watcher in WebStorm.

Comment: Try running `where pug`. You need to locate `pug.cmd` or maybe `pug.bat` file (sorry, not using Pug myself so do not know exact executable name). Try checking other places as well (e.g. on my setup (Node v10.15.3, npm 6.4.1) global stuff gets installed into `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to run Pug in command line (to use it in a file watcher), you need installing `pug-cli` package globally (`npm install pug-cli -g`), see https://github.com/pugjs/pug#command-line. This command will install `pug.cmd` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\` (that must be on your `%PATH%` already)